# PHP not decoding POST

Tags: php

Is it normal for PHP not to decode $_POST sent as application/x-www-form-urlencoded through AJAX?

I want to use urldecode but it gets rid of my + characters. Help?

:

```
15:51:55.490[755ms][total 755ms] Status: 200[OK]
POST  Load Flags[LOAD_BYPASS_CACHE  LOAD_BACKGROUND  ] Content Size[72] Mime Type[text/html]
   Request Headers:
      Host[]
      User-Agent[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8]
      Accept[text/html, */*]
      Accept-Language[en-us,en;q=0.5]
      Accept-Encoding[gzip,deflate]
      Accept-Charset[ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7]
      Keep-Alive[115]
      Proxy-Connection[keep-alive]
      Content-Type[application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8]
      X-Requested-With[XMLHttpRequest]
      Content-Length[164]
      Pragma[no-cache]
      Cache-Control[no-cache]
   Post Data:
      id[133]
      content[%253Cp%253E%250A%2509Test%2520test%2520-%2520this%2520will%2520disappear%253A%2520%2B%253C%2Fp%253E%250A]
      title[Plus%2520character%2520not%2520working]
   Response Headers:
      Via[1.1 KIGALI]
      Connection[Keep-Alive]
      Proxy-Connection[Keep-Alive]
      Content-Length[72]
      Date[Mon, 02 Aug 2010 03:51:55 GMT]
      Content-Type[text/html; charset=utf-8]
      Server[Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)]
      X-Powered-By[PHP/5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4]
      Vary[Accept-Encoding]
      Keep-Alive[timeout=15, max=100]
```

Comment: This is what urldecode does (straight from the doc: *Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.* ). Please post some sample code. And no, $_POST will work the same way for a regular or ajax request.

Comment: no, it is not normal asking questions without bringing some example to make others understand what are you talking about

Comment: Please show your PHP code, since you have the `+` signs properly encoded as `%2B` in the Post Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Part of [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)'s functionality is to turn `+` signs into spaces.* To get around this, you should urlencode any `+` signs in your string, so they turn into `%2B`

So:

```
<?php
$theTag = 'c++';
urldecode($theTag);
  // output is "c  "
$theTag = urlencode($theTag);
urldecode($theTag);
  // output is "c++"
?>
```

Now, [the superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php). I'm not sure about `$_POST`. But it well may be decoded too.

---

From your question, I'm not sure exactly what you're dealing with, but looking over the comments on urldecode in the PHP manual, [here is a comment you may be interested in](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#82281):

`It's worth pointing out that if you are using AJAX and need to encode strings that are being sent to a PHP application, you may not need to decode them in PHP.`

```
<?php
echo stripslashes(nl2br($_POST['message']));
?>
```

`Will properly output a message sent with the javascript code if the message is encoded:`

```
message = encodeURIComponent(message)
```

`And is sent with an AJAX POST request with the header:`

```
ajaxVar.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP does indeed decode your data. The problem is it's doubly encoded.

Take the second variable:

```
glopes@nebm:~$  php -r "echo urldecode(urldecode('%253Cp%253E%250A%2509Test%25
20test%2520-%2520this%2520will%2520disappear%253A%2520%2B%253C%2Fp%253E%250A')
);"
<p>
        Test test - this will disappear:  </p>
```

As you can see, you have to call `urldecode` twice. So there's something wrong on the Javascript side that's making it be doubly encoded.

---

> Is it normal for PHP not to decode $_POST sent as application/x-www-form-urlencoded through AJAX?

No, it certainly isn't. POST here the HTTP request headers, if it doesn't work, so we can try to see if there's something wrong with the request.

> I want to use urldecode but it gets rid of my + characters. Help?

You can use [`rawurldecode`](http://www.php.net/rawurldecode) instead. However, I don't understand why you'd need this.

Comment: I added my request headers. Thanks :)

Comment: @David I'll see if I can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, I was having the same problem.

JavaScript code to send data:

```
var content = '<br>%20``+++dqwcdwdw';    
content = urlencode(content);
content = encodeURIComponent(content);
```

then the data is sent by POST and 
`("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");`

Here is the php code to receive data:

```
$content = urldecode($_POST['thepostfieldname']);
$content =  stripslashes(nl2br($content));
```

This works for me :)